# Concatenar una URL con los datos de variables VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo una consulta para muchos será algo muy sencillo pero me esta sacando canas este tema..

tengo una aplicacion web, escrita en vue usando template jade esta trae unas variables y necesito concatenar una url con esos datos de las variables..

```
grd-row
          .grd-row-col-3-6 Exchange:
          .grd-row-col-3-6 {{ data.watch.exchange }}
        .grd-row
          .grd-row-col-3-6 Currency:
          .grd-row-col-3-6 {{ data.watch.currency }}
        .grd-row
          .grd-row-col-3-6 Asset:
          .grd-row-col-3-6 {{ data.watch.asset }}
```

Ahora supongamos que las variables se componen así :
 data.watch.currency = BTC , data.watch.asset= BNB  , data.watch.exchange= binance

```
em You can track this Pair
       a(href='https://www.binance.com/en/trade/pro/' + data.watch.asset + "_" + data.watch.currency, target='_blank')   on  {{ data.watch.exchange }}
```

lo que espero es que me concatene la url quede así  y me generes esta URL https://www.binance.com/en/trade/pro/BNB_BTC

y lo que quiero en respuesta es

You can track this Pair on [binance](https://www.binance.com/en/trade/pro/BNB_BTC)

Comment: Ahí solo veo jade, agrega todo el código que tengas de `vue js` para reproducir tu escenario. Gracias por tu colaboración :D

Comment: Tienes que poner el `a(:href='https...)'`. Fíjate en los `:` (dos puntos) antes del href, ahora ya puedes usar las variables para concatenar con los `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente estes recibiendo este lindo error:

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the
>   colon shorthand instead.

Y eso es porque exactamente paso eso. Para poder usar variables dentro de un atributo, tenes que usar lo que dice el error. En este caso, usamos `:href` para decirle que ese es el atributo que vamos a armar, y lo ponemos entre comillas dobles, para luego generar un string con comillas simples y sumando las variables que necesitamos.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!',
    watch1: 'parte1',
    watch2: 'parte2'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <a :href="'https://www.binance.com/en/trade/pro/'+ watch1+'_'+watch2">link </a>
</div>
```